# adding years getting invalid number error in case statement only - ORA-01722

Tags: sql, oracle, case, ora-01722

Forgive me as I am new to this.  I am trying to add a year to a date in a query.  The year to be added is based on the month/day in the database.  If the date is prior to November 1st then the year will be 2017 if it is after November 1st then it will be 2018.  I have tried this a few ways (see below) and can get the years added in a query but when I put them in a case statement I get the 'Invalid Number' error.

Using to_char on the date:

```
   CASE
      WHEN to_char(au.creat_ts, 'MMDD') >= to_char('11/01/2018', 'MMDD') THEN
       to_char(to_date( '2017'||to_char(au.creat_ts,'MMDDHH24MISS'),
'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
      ELSE
      to_char(to_date( '2018'||to_char(au.creat_ts,'MMDDHH24MISS'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    END cmpltn_dt,
```

Adding Months:

```
  CASE
      WHEN to_char(au.creat_ts, 'MMDD') >= to_char('11/01/2018', 'MMDD') THEN
       trunc(add_months(au.creat_ts,
                        floor(months_between(SYSDATE, au.creat_ts) / 12) * 12)) --calcx --add years
      ELSE
       trunc(add_months(au.creat_ts,
                        (floor(months_between(SYSDATE, au.creat_ts) / 12) - 1) * 12))
    END calcx,
```

These run in select from dual statements with no error. Any ideas?  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question and show table definition and sample table data.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the date is prior to Nov 2017? I mean, what should be displayed?

Comment: It should add 1 year less.  So basically I am adding years to a date.  Think of it as trying to get the x year anniversary if date is after November 1st and x-1 year anniversary if prior to November 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AU.CREAT_TS` is `DATE`, this works OK (meaning: it doesn't fail):

```
SQL> with au (creat_ts) as
  2    (select date '2018-12-05' from dual
  3    )
  4  select
  5    CASE WHEN to_char(au.creat_ts, 'MMDD') >= to_char(to_date('11/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MMDD') THEN
  6              trunc(add_months(au.creat_ts, floor(months_between(SYSDATE, au.creat_ts) / 12) * 12))
  7         ELSE trunc(add_months(au.creat_ts, (floor(months_between(SYSDATE, au.creat_ts) / 12) - 1) * 12))
  8    END calcx
  9  from au
 10  ;

CALCX
-------------------
05.12.2018 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Note the difference: you used

```
  CASE WHEN to_char(au.creat_ts, 'MMDD') >= to_char('11/01/2018', 'MMDD') THEN
```

and it raises the error because `'11/01/2018'` is a string; it is **not** a date. If you want to use a date, you have to tell Oracle so. How? See my working example.

Comment: Thanks so much for the example and explanation.  This worked!

Answer (score 0):

The errors are coming from the two appearances of this clause:

```
to_char('11/01/2018', 'MMDD')
```

You're passing a string as the first argument (**not** a date), and Oracle defaults to trying to convert that string to a number - which throws the error you see.

You either need to pass in an actual date, by explicitly converting the string:

```
to_char(to_date('11/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'MMDD')
```

or with an ANSI literal:

```
to_char(date '2018-11-01', 'MMDD')
```

or if it's really a fixed value don't convert it at all, just do:

```
'1101'
```

or if you are being passed that streing from elsewhere - and you're sure about the format, of course - us `substr()` to extract the bits you need without trying to bounce it through a date.

Incidentally, converting values to and from dates and concatenating bits of strings together looks a bit messy and error-prone. And if that fixed date is always the first of a month, you could modify your case expression to only look at the month, e.g. via `extract()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!  This really helps!